# Material ui autocomplete how to render options that do not have labels with icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

My options structure is like below

```js
const options = 'option1', 'option2'];
```

I want to render option with icon like this:

[image]

My current code for renderOption is :

```js
renderOption = (options => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SearchIcon>
        <img src = {searchIcon.svg}/>
      </SearchIcon>
      {options}
    </Fragment>
  )
})
```

But I got error:

[image]

Can anyone help me render options that don't have labels with icon?

Thank you!

Comment: Normally that icon indicates, where the user would have to click to start the search. Why do you want to use that icon for every option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see your code in order to help you fix your issue according to your need, but you are close to where you needed to be, which is to utilize the `renderOption` props for `<Autocomplete>` component.

In this case, what you want to do is actually this

```
    <Autocomplete
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <li {...props}>
          <SearchIcon />
          {option.label}
        </li>
      )}
      // ... and rest of the props
    />
```

See doc for `renderOption` API for `Autocomplete` here https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-renderOption

CodeSandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-goldberg-kqq5pq?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: Thanks for your help!  But my options structure is [option1, option2], it doesn't have a label. Then what should I put in "{option.label}" ?

Comment: In that case, just `option` will suffice, because MUI automatically knows what is passed in for the autocomplete. I have updated the CodeSandbox demo that matches more to your scenario so you can refer to :)